# Does window.print() work for mobile devices?

Tags: html

I am using

```
<a title="Print Screen" alt="Print Screen" onclick="window.print();" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;">PRINT BUTTON</a>
```

on my website. (a WordPress responsive theme)

Will this code also work on mobile devices?

Comment: What do you expect this to do on a mobile device?

Comment: Hi,If a mobile device is set up to print (I understand there are different phones, many ways/ apps ect.. it

Comment: I don't know enough about mobile, but I didn't realize that any of them were capable of printing.  Do you have a smartphone you could possibly test this on?

Comment: I don't, but I have acces to one.  On the internet I see Eprint, AIRprint ,  google cloud print....  It appears this is a business type of apps., maybe students... Jerry

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not, since mobile devices usually do not have a printer attached.